# 'Queries per day' limit exceeded despite not exhausting quota limit

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, quota

Over the last few months, users of my application are receiving the following error:

> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:******'. [403]
> Errors [
> Message[Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:*****'.] Location[ - ] Reason[rateLimitExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]]

#### Issue 1

According to the API console (where the limit was at 5.2m at the start of the week), the used quota never rose above 4.8m. In fact, it reports 4.79m twice so this would seem to be a limit of some kind.

API daily quota usage screenshot

[image: img_api_daily_quota]

I am in GMT timezone, so the new quota is available at 08:00 local time - you can see quota utilization is 4.79m on Thu 19-Nov, but the "Errors by credential" graph shows errors starting from 03:30 on Fri 20-Nov and continuing until 08:00.

Errors by the credential screenshot

[image: img_errors_by_the_credential]

So clearly I am being limited on the daily quota, but why is this happening when I should still have 400k API calls available?

#### Issue 2

Google documentation indicates [rateLimitExceeded](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) should be treated with exponential backoff, (which I am doing) but this seems wrong if it is related to the daily quota being exhausted. I would expect to see [dailyLimitExceeded](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded) being reported, where the solution is to wait until 08:00 GMT.

I think this change in reporting of the error also started a few months back.

Are these bugs or am I missing something?

Comment: Google quota is calculated from West coast USA time which may effect how your reports look.  Have you considered applying for an extension?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Google Workspace support? https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213

Comment: @DaImTo I have tried changing my computer's time to PST - this does alter how the API metrics page looks, with the "error by credentials" graph resetting at midnight instead of 0800. However, the daily usage graph does not change. I do wonder if this is just a bug in that graph, but it doesn't even seem to be possible to download the raw data behind it.
I have successfully applied for quota increases, but it bugs me I'm "missing" 400k quota!

Comment: @Aerials I'm only on a free personal account, so Google [directed me here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/support) for support.

Comment: Quota is caclutated on googles servers it doesnt matter what time your computer is set to.  Please edit your question and incude your code.

Comment: @DaImTo I think you miss the point - if Google's server quota calculations are displayed on the bar graph using the web browser's local time, then it could be assigning 8 hours of quota usage to the wrong day and therefore explain why the quota limit value is seemingly never reached. Given the API metric line graphs DO change according to computer time, my test was valid. I'm not sure what code you want to see that may help isolate the issue further?

Comment: Dont get hung up with what is displayed in the graph, its an estimate it is not live calculated, it is not 100% accurate.  What you should look at is the the response coming back when you make a request is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that Google has introduced a [new API quota management](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota) of "queries per minute", which a client should handle through the the use of exponential backoff. This is in contrast to the "queries per day" quota, for which a  project would have to wait until 08:00 UTC before new quota would be available.

I therefore strongly suspect that the anomalies in API usage reporting leading up to this change were related to Google developing this change in approach. Indeed for a month or more, the *Queries per Day* graph in my screenshots showed no activity at all, before finally being replaced with the new *Queries Per Minute* graph.